# Getting text between xml tags using AWK or SED in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delimited by comma using AWK or SED with the tags below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460542/delimited-by-comma-using-awk-or-sed-with-the-tags-below)

I have text in below format.

```
[AccountID]
 [CallerID]
  [BilledAccountAttributes]
  1111111
  1111111
  1111111
[\BilledAccountAttributes]
[OBIOTax]
10
20
30
[\OBIOTax]
[RINOTax]
777
888
999
[\RINOTax]
[\CallerID]
[\AccountID]

[AccountID]
[CallerID]
[BilledAccountAttributes]
2222222
2222222
2222222
[\BilledAccountAttributes]
[OBIOTax]
40
50
60
[\OBIOTax]
[\CallerID]
[\AccountID]
```

And I want output in below format (Delimited by comma and put ZERO when RINOTAX is not displayed.)

```
1111111,1111111,1111111,  10,20,30,  777,888,999  
2222222,2222222,2222222,  40,50,60,    0,  0,  0
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this.

Comment: Sed and AWK are the wrong tools for the job... the most powerful tool that either one has for parsing is regular expressions, and regular expressions are bad for parsing xml -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. You're much better off using xpath or the xml libraries of your favorite scripting language.

Comment: @Barton Chittenden: The above text is not XML. It rather looks like some line-based format that resembles XML in that it has start and end tags. If every value is on its own line then awk would do the job.

Comment: Absolutely identical to [Delimited by comma using AWK or SED with the tags below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460542/delimited-by-comma-using-awk-or-sed-with-the-tags-below). Is this homework?

Comment: ... Ok, turn square brackets into angle brackets and backslashes into forward slashes, and it might as well be XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk for that.

My approach would be to check if a line contains only a number. This can be done with regular expressions. awk's documentation tells you how to use this with awk.

If a line contains `[\AccountID]`, print a newline.

I would use a marker variable to remember if there has been a previous value in for current line printed. Set this marker to true if a value was printed. Then print out a comma depending on this marker. If you write a newline (see above) set the marker to false. So, the before next number, no comma will be printed.

Some pseudo code (shell like syntax):

```
begin { marker = 0; }
{
  if 'line contains number' then
    if 'marker == 1' then print ','
    print current line
    set marker to 1
  elsif 'line is end account id' then
    set marker to 0
    print '\n'
  fi
}
```

I hope this helps you to find a solution.

Comment: But this won't help for point "put ZERO when RINOTAX is not displayed"

Comment: Yes, that's right. I overlooked this requirement. Sorry. Seems you need a real parser as Barton said.